# Firebase Read/Write rules with custom keys/value compare

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a simple location tracking app. On device I've installed my location broadcast service and its updating the location data on Firebase Realtime database. On my second device I've Monitoring Activity with Google maps. So far its working fine and the datebase is update and location is reflecting on the Monitoring device map activity.

But I want to set certain rules as only user/device with a specific token/ID, which will be generated at the start of each location broadcast on the broadcasting device and stored on Firebase RDB, will have access to the location data of the device. The Token/ID will be shared with monitoring device through my server.

Now I'm trying to write some rules here to check if the Token/ID provided by the Monitoring device is available and allowed for monitoring.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$userID":{
      ".read" : "data.child('boadCastingID').val() === 'ASy34345-5KJHSDF3-34k3-334nH'"
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do so? I've found some other methods where the datasnapshot is fetched and then compared for different values which I found a little unsafe as the data will be already available on the monitoring device but not visible regardless of access.

Comment: Security rules on their own are meaningless without seeing the code that exercises them. Please edit your question to show: 1) the JSON data that is being read and secured here, 2) the code that read this data, 3) the problem/error that you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to pass a custom value into the security rules when you read data from your database.

There are only two ways to pass data to your security rules:

1. As part of the path that you're reading.
2. As a parameter of a query.
3. As part of the user authentication token that is being sent with each request.

So if you want to secure data access based on the broadcast ID, you'll either have to make that a part of the path, of the query, or add it to the user's auth token as a custom claim.

#### Adding the broadcast ID to the path

To secure the access to the data based on the broadcast ID, you can store all data for a given broadcast ID under that broadcast ID in the database:

```
broadcastIds: {
  "broadcastID-1234-ddolhqsdakp": { ... },
  "broadcastID-woepaacaiuq-3456": { ... }
}
```

Now we won't allow access on `broadcastIds`, but **will** allow access on each child node:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "broadcastIds": {
      ".read": true
  }
}
```

With this setup a user can only read data for a broadcast ID if they already know that broadcast ID. If your broadcast IDs are sufficiently unguessable, this is a reasonable way to secure access to that data.

---

#### Securely query the data

Alternatively you can store the broadcast ID in each user node, pass it along in the query to the database, and then secure that query. In this scenario the JSON could look like this:

```
users: {
  "user1uid": {
    broadcastId: "abc",
    ...
  },
  "user2uid": {
    broadcastId: "xyz",
    ...
  }
}
```

The query would be something like:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
usersRef.orderByChid("broadcastId").equalTo("abc")...
```

And then the security rules to allow that query (and reject other reads) would be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "broadcastIds": {
      ".read": "query.orderByChild == 'broadcastId' && query.equalTo == data.child('boadCastingID').val()"
  }
}
```

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [securely querying data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#query-based_rules).

---

#### Put the broadcast ID in the user's ID token

The final approach would be to [store the broadcast ID in the user's auth token as a custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims). You do this by making a call to the Firebase Admin SDK in a trusted environment, for example on a Node.js server with:

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {broadcastID: "abc"})
```

You can then check for the presence of the custom claim in your security rules with:

```
".read": "auth.token.broadcastID == 'abc'"
```

Comment: Thankyou so much @Frank. Your second solution is the one that i was looking for. I knew the logic and everything but didn't know that i can pass query with my request to validate. For other two options, 1st one is also a good solutions since the BroadcastID is the main node and if requesting device don't have BroadcastID, its not going to find anything regardless of the rules. And about last option here, I'm using Anonymous Login so i don't know if it will go well with all users since anonymous login is anonymous with auth token and everything. But for now 2nd is the way to go. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Joe. I think custom claims should work with anonymous auth, but agreed that the other to options are likelly a better fit for your use-case.